# NSIDC sea ice .bin file to raster()

Tags: gis, geospatial, bin, r-raster

I am trying to follow the example give [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/graticule/vignettes/graticule.html) under "A polar example"

This example uses sea-ice data in .bin format to plot as raster. I am trying the same with a different file available from the [original ftp server](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/nsidc0051_gsfc_nasateam_seaice/final-gsfc/south/daily/2010/) of the National Snow and Ice Data Center. Hence, I assume there should be no issue. However, when I try to prompt R run the following script

```
# from NSIDC sea ice concentration file
baseurl <- "ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/"

f2 <- paste(baseurl, 
        "nsidc0051_gsfc_nasateam_seaice/final-gsfc/north/daily/2013/nt_20130111_f17_v1.1_n.bin",
        sep='')

if (!file.exists(basename(f2))) download.file(f2, basename(f2), mode = "wb")
ice2 <- raster(basename(f2))
```

> Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.

Where am I going wrong? is the .bin file corrupted? Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found a solution on github that works really nice.

https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/nsidcICE.R

Just replace in line 14 of the script

```
hemi <- tolower(substr(bx, 21L, 21L))
```

by

```
hemi <- tolower(substr(bx, 22L, 22L)),
```

as the new name structure differs slightly from the original one by one digit namly a dot in the v1.1 sequence!

Compare:

```
"nt_19781119_f07_v01_s.bin"
```

to the version I was interested in

```
"nt_20130111_f17_v1.1_n.bin"
```