# How to open and convert to data.frame from bin file with R

Tags: r

Using the ***readBin*** Function, I tried to open .bin files obtained from National Snow & Ice Data Center (NSIDC).

However I didn't understand how to get the data from .bin files.

.bin file information :

The file format consists of a 300-byte descriptive header followed by a two-dimensional array of
one-byte values containing the data. The file header is composed of:

• a 21-element array of 6-byte character strings that contain information such as polar
stereographic grid characteristics

• a 24-byte character string containing the file name

• a 80-character string containing an optional image title

• a 70-byte character string containing ancillary information such as data origin, data set
creation date, etc

Comment: Far too little information. Which dataset? When I go to their website I see data in a wide variety of formats, but ... no .bin files. And ... what was teh code you used to "try"?

Comment: I fear readers may encounter difficulties with accessing data. I see this when trying to get one of their datasets: `An Earthdata Login account is required to access these data.`

Comment: Maybe this question is of help to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519685/nsidc-sea-ice-bin-file-to-raster